# Divergent or Convergent Question

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Prove that this statement is convergent or divergent.

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n^3}}$$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Multiply top and bottom by $\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}$, and use Comparison with a suitable series that you know converges.